# Japanese Input in Laravel Login Form

Tags: php, laravel, character-encoding, cjk

I fail login every time I try to input the password "123456" in  Japanese IME Half-width Alphanumeric . In English Keyboard is OK. 
When I dumped input value in login controller . The Password value showing "ﾇﾌｱｳｴ" instead of "123456". Do I have to do something with encoding?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your form and it is not an encoding issue. It is an IME setting.

Your input method is set to "kana", where the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 on the number row correspond to ヌ, フ, ア, ウ, エ, オ. Setting it to "romaji" will fix the issue, as will switching to English input mode.